# Subselect, joins and O/R mapping

Tags: join, primary-key, left-join, subquery

i am following struts 2 and hibernate 5.
I have two tables A and B with different primary keys A_ID and B_ID.
They have common columns like model, name.

In my hbm file, I didnt refer to any of the above tables instead I have a subselect query which joins the two tables.

The mappings in the hbm file is

```
<id name="a_id" column="A_ID" />

<property name="b_model" column="B_model"/>
```

When i ran the hibernate query generated. I got the following output in MySql

```
A_Id    B_model other columns
111     3131
222     2121
222     4141
333     5151
```

But the list returned when the query is executed is

```
list(0) = 111 and 3131
list(1) = 222 and 2121
list(2) = 222 and **2121**
list(3) = 333 and 5151.
```

My question is why didnt list(2) didnt have 4141 instead of 2121.

And please let me know what i should to get the same (i.e) i need 4141 in list(2).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it is creating one object for the primary key row 222 and setting it to the first value 2121. And hence the next value which is also 222 contains the first value 2121. Please confirm this and a possible solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i guessed the tuples are returned as objects. Hence for A-Id 222 the B_mod is set as 2121. I used row_num() function to get distinct row nums for each row and used it as a primary key column to get all the rows. This may not be an exact solution but still it worked :-)